# Better jQuery Embed Code validation (user input via textarea)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, embed

I'm working on a site where users can paste in embed codes from the likes of *twitter*, *youtube*, *instagram*, *facebook*, etc. The Embed code is validated and saved if valid.

The users can then see and edit the code and this is where some code fails validation. E.g. Twitter embed codes may contain `&lt;` (aka '<') in the post name/text. When pasting in the code originally it passes validation as it contains `&lt;`, but when displaying the code back to the user the browser shows `<` in the `textarea` and this is then submitted if the user clicks save. Our validation function treats this as the start of a `tag` and the validation fails.

**Possible solution 1:**

Better validation. The validation we use now looks like this It basically finds the tags (by looking for '<' etc) and checks that each open tag has a closing tag. There must be a better/standard/commonly used way:

```
(function($) {
$.validateEmbedCode = function(code) {
    //validating
    var input = code;
    var tags = [];
    $.each(input.split('\n'), function (i, line) {
        $.each(line.match(/<[^>]*[^/]>/g) || [], function (j, tag) {
            var matches = tag.match(/<\/?([a-z0-9]+)/i);
            if (matches) {
                tags.push({tag: tag, name: matches[1], line: i+1, closing: tag[1] == '/'});
            }
        });
    });
    if (tags.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    var openTags = [];
    var error = false;
    var indent = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = tags[i];
        if (tag.closing) {
            // This tag is a closing tag. Decide what to do accordingly.
            var closingTag = tag;
            if (isSelfClosingTag(closingTag.name)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (openTags.length == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            var openTag = openTags[openTags.length - 1];
            if (closingTag.name != openTag.name) {
                return false;
            } else {
                openTags.pop();
            }
        } else {
            var openTag = tag;
            if (isSelfClosingTag(openTag.name)) {
                continue;
            }
            openTags.push(openTag);
        }
    }
    if (openTags.length > 0) {
        var openTag = openTags[openTags.length - 1];
        return false;
    }
    return true
};
```

}

**Possible solution 2:**

Encode the text containing '<' (i.e. `textLine.replace(/</g, '&lt;')`) without encoding tags like `<blockquote class="...>`.

I've been experimenting with something like:

```
$(widget.find("textarea[name='code']").val()).find('*')
.each(function(){
    // validate $(this).text() here. Need to get text only line by
    // line as some elements look like <p>some text <a ...>text
    // </a>more text etc</p>
});
```

**Possible solution 3:**

Display `&lt;` as `&lt;` and not `<` in the browser/`textarea`. We use icanhaz for templating (much like moustache).

Using `date.code = '&lt;'` with `<textarea name="code">{{{code}}}</textarea>` in the template does not work, neither does `{{code}}`.

Answer (score 0):

So I played some more and the following works, but I am still interested in suggestions for better embed code validation or better answers.

After the edit form (inc `textarea`) code is created using the icanhaz template (i.e. after `widget = ich.editEmbedWidgetTemplate(encoded_data);`) I do the following to encode instances of `<` etc into `&lt;` etc. `'` has to be encoded manually using `replace`.

```
var embedCode = '';
$( widget.find("textarea[name='code']").val() )
.filter('*')
.each(function(){
    embedCode += this.outerHTML.replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
});
widget.find("textarea[name='code']").val(embedCode);
```